# In C, is there any way to clean up if a longjmp "passes through" my function?

Tags: c, resource-cleanup, setjmp

I have the following call stack:

```
library_function_1 ====> my_function ====> library_function_2
                   calls             calls
```

In C++, if `library_function_2` throws an exception and `library_function_1` catches it, `my_function` can safely clean up (release resources etc.) using destructors (i.e. RAII).

In C#, similarly, `my_function` could clean up using `try`/`finally` and `using` statements.

In C, if `library_function_1` uses `setjmp` and `library_function_2` `longjmp`s back to it, is there any way for `my_function` to clean up?

Comment: Short and really only answer is no, it's not possible. `setjmp`/`longjmp` doesn't to stack unwinding like e.g. C++ exceptions.

Comment: It *is* possible, but only if `library_function_1`'s library exposes some kind of explicit mechanism for `my_function` to register & deregister a cleanup handler.  (Which is more or less what one flavour of C++ exception handling does automatically.)

Comment: `setjmp`/`longjmp` really is a really, really ugly hack that seemed ingenious to its creators back in the stone age of computing. We have accumulated a bit more wisdom since. `setjmp` is really just saving the current stack pointer and return address and `longjmp` restores these two values to their saved state. This utterly ignores what's on the stack when the jump is made, the only thing that happens is the reset. This kind of blissful ignorance is a very fertile ground for many a bug farm. So, best forget that `setjmp`/`longjmp` ever existed, you will be a better programmer for it.

Comment: "best forget that `setjmp`/`longjmp` ever existed" - Unfortunately that's not possible in this situation, because I'm using a library that makes use of these functions.

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry for you. I know your plight. The errors of our past keep haunting us. For me, such a behavior of a library would be a really good argument to switch to some other library that does not use `setjmp`/`longjmp`, *provided there is such an alternative*. If you don't have an alternative, you have my sympathies for your bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is if the passing of the `setjmp()` info from the function `library_function_1` is made through your function (or you having access to it) you can save the info you get from it, and do another `setjmp()` into your function code, and passing that to `library_function_2`... in that case, you are intercepting the call nesting and the `setjmp()` returning... the inner function will return to you, because it is what it received from up... and then you'll have to do a `longjmp()` to the place you received from `library_function_1`.

But if that information is not accessible to you, there's no way to intercept it.